# I am trying to save a string to a MYSQL table from a radiobutton in java/Android studio

Tags: java, strings, mysql, android, hash-map

I am trying to save a radiobutton string if it clicked. I am making a survey where I need to save a "yes" or "no" into a MYSQL table using volley. I am having a little trouble doing this and have tried to use the method below. Does anyone have any insight on how to do this? Right now I am

Please find my code below:

````
private void MCIRadioSave() {
        GoToMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GoToJournal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GoToMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        GoToJournal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(yesBTN.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes1 = this.yesBTN.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no1 = this.noBTN.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        if(yesBTN2.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes2 = this.yesBTN2.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no2 = this.noBTN2.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        if(yesBTN3.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes3 = this.yesBTN3.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no3 = this.noBTN3.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        if(yesBTN4.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes4 = this.yesBTN4.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no4 = this.noBTN4.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        if(yesBTN5.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes5 = this.yesBTN5.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no5 = this.noBTN5.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        if(yesBTN6.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes6 = this.yesBTN6.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no6 = this.noBTN6.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        if(yesBTN7.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes7 = this.yesBTN7.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no7 = this.noBTN7.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        if(yesBTN8.isChecked())
        {
            final String yes8 = this.yesBTN8.getText().toString().trim();
        }
        else
        {
            final String no8 = this.noBTN8.getText().toString().trim();
        }



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MCI_SAVE,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                            if (success.equals("1")) {
                                Toast.makeText(checkin1.this, "Thank you for completing your check in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                GoToMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                GoToJournal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(checkin1.this, "Register Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(checkin1.this, LoginActivity.class));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(checkin1.this, "Register Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            GoToMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            GoToJournal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(checkin1.this, "Register Error " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("Gallery error =>", error.toString());
                        GoToMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        GoToJournal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Q1Medical", yes1 || no1 );
                params.put("Q2Safety",  no2 || yes2 );
                params.put("Q3Completing",  no3 || yes3 );
                params.put("Q4TP", no4 || yes4 );
                params.put("Q5Supervisor",  no5 || yes5 );
                params.put("Q6English",  no5 || yes5 );
                params.put("Q7Hours",  no6 || yes6 );
                params.put("Q8Additional",  no7 || yes7 );
                params.put("Q8Additional",  no8 || yes8 );

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } ```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It sounds like this code isn't working to the best of your knowledge, which would not be in line with what is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. When you have implemented the code feel free to [edit] your post to include it for a review.

Comment: (`save a radiobutton string when the button is clicked`?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `yesX` / `noX` variables are local only to the if else block you declared them in.

```java
final String foo;
if (yesBTN4.isChecked()) {
  foo = "bar";
} else if(noBTN4.isChecked()) {
  foo = "barz";
}
```

Which brings me to another choice you decided to make. How are you going to determine if you're passing `yes2` or `no2` into your database. That would require another check. Instead have one variable to store per question response. Noticed how I used one variable for both yes and no and it equals different things based on branch.

Finally, there is no reason to call `trim()` on the the radiobutton `.getText()` because the text is typically what YOU specified it to be. So unless you are doing something crazy like `RadioButton rb5 = new RadioButton(" Hello, World!    ");` there isn't a reason to make that method call.